# I am trying to split the path but getting correct commands

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, cut

I am trying to split the path but not getting correct commands

i.e. `/bin/bash/test/path/to/split` and should be split/cut in two parts delimited with string i.e. split on string `/to/`.

Expected output: `/bin/bash/test/path` and `/split`

I have tried cut command options but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

`cut` can only take a single character¹ delimiter.

`bash` variables can be processed thus:

```
❯ testfull="/bin/bash/test/path/to/split"
❯ testpre="${test%/to/*}"
❯ testpost="${test#*/to/}"
❯ echo "$testpre is separate from $testpost"
/bin/bash/test/path is separate from split
```

Where `%pattern*` strips everything after the pattern and the `#*pattern` strips everything before. If you have multiple instances of the pattern, doubling up the `#` or `%` lets you pick the first or last instance.

With `awk` you can specify a string delimiter with `-F` and pick whatever remaining segment you like:

```
❯ echo "/bin/bash/test/path/to/split" | awk -F'/to/' '{print $1" separate from "$2}'
/bin/bash/test/path separate from split
```

---

<sup>¹ with several `cut` implementations including GNU `cut`, it's even limited to single-byte characters.</sup>

Comment: You should either use `##` and `%` or `#` and `%%` or you'll get confusing results if there's more than one occurrence of `/to/` in the path. You may also want to take into account the cases where `/to/` is not found in the path.

Comment: Since file paths can contain newline characters, processing them line-based like you do with `awk` is wrong. You can however pass the path as argument to `awk` and use `split()` in a BEGIN statement to do the splitting. Again, you may want to take into account the cases where `/to/` occurs more or less than once.

Answer (score 0):

In the `zsh` shell, you can split a string on arbitrary separators with the `s` parameter expansion flag.

```
$ file=$'/path/to//to/dir/and\nor/to/file'
$ parts=( "${(@s[/to/])file}" )
$ typeset parts
parts=( /path '' $'dir/and\nor' file )
$ printf ' - <%s>\n' "$parts[@]"
 - </path>
 - <>
 - <dir/and
or>
 - <file>
```

Here picking a contrived example with a file path containing more than one occurrence of `/to/` including two consecutive ones and a newline character as a  reminder of potential pitfalls you may have to worry about.

The `@`s combined with quoting is to preserve empty elements (here the one between the consecutive occurrences of `/to/`).

You can join the parts together with the `j` parameter expansion flag:

```
$ print -r -- ${(j[/to/])parts}
/path/to//to/dir/and
or/to/file
```

In bash4.4+, you can do something approaching by offloading to `perl` for instance to do the splitting:

```
$ file=$'/path/to//to/dir/and\nor/to/file'
$ readarray -td '' parts < <(perl -l0se 'print for split /\Q$s\E/, $file, -1' -- -file="$file" -s=/to/)
$ typeset -p parts
declare -a parts=([0]="/path" [1]="" [2]=$'dir/and\nor' [3]="file")
```

Beware though that `perl` works byte-wise rather than character-wise. OK here for a separator that starts and ends with `/` whose encoding is guaranteed not to be found in other characters, but may otherwise break some characters in the middle with other separators.

In `zsh`, see also:

```
$ file=/bin/bash/test/path/to/split
$ print -r -- $file:h:h
/bin/bash/test/path
```

(`h`ead of `h`ead)

```
$ print -r -- $file:t
split
```

(`t`ail).

Same as in csh/tcsh. `bash` also supports those `:h`, `:t` *modifiers* but only in history expansion, they can't be applied to parameter expansions.